# Using different codes but getting same results

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, variables, range

In both code A and code B the output is the same. I understand that for the output to be the same the code doesn't have to be same line to line. But if you look at it in both code A and B the variable "word_length" has different values.

in code a) the variable equals only the total number of characters of the chosen word.

In code B I subtracted 1 from the total length of the chosen word becuz in lists the computer starts counting the position of characters from 0.

In both codes the variable is used in the "for loop" in the same way. And the output is the same even though the value of the variable "word_length" is different.

Could anyone explain why this is so?

## Code A

```
import random

word_list = ["aardvark", "baboon", "camel"]

chosen_word = random.choice(word_list)

print(f'Pssst, the solution is {chosen_word}.')


display = []

word_length = len(chosen_word)

for _ in range(word_length):
       display += "_"
guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()

for position in range(word_length):
     letter = chosen_word[position]

     if letter == guess:
         display[position] = letter
print(display)
```

## Code B

```
import random
word_list = ["aardvark", "baboon", "camel"]
chosen_word = random.choice(word_list)
 
print(f'Pssst, the solution is {chosen_word}.')
 
display = []
for letter in chosen_word:
   display += "_"
word_length = len(chosen_word)-1

guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()

for position in range(word_length):
        if guess == chosen_word[position]:
            display[position] = guess

print(display)
```

Answer (score 1):

`range()` yields an open range, e.g. `range(5)` yields (0, 1, 2, 3, 4).

The code where you subtract 1 from the length of the word thus has a bug where you can never be able to guess the last character of the word.